# jQuery UI Dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

when creating a dialog with buttons like:

```
buttons:    {
            'button text': function(){                              
                // do something
            },
```

do I have access to the button within the click event handler?

```
$(this)
```

is the context/jQuery object of the whole dialog.

I doubt I have to be such creative as

```
$(this).find('button').attr(...)
```

to disabled a button there ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The documentation for [`dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons) says:

> The property key is the text of the
>   button. The value is the callback
>   function for when the button is
>   clicked. The context of the callback
>   is the dialog element; **if you need
>   access to the button, it is available
>   as the target of the event object**.

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({
    'title': 'My Dialog Header',
    'buttons': {
        'My Button': function(event) {
            // here is the modification of the button
            // opacity set to 25%, all events unbound
            $(event.target).css({opacity: 0.25}).unbind();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The format of the buttons in the dialog is a `<button>` with a `<span>` inside, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Button text</span>
</button>
```

So when you click, the actual `click` event happens on that `<span>` or `<button>`, depending on your styling (margin on the span for example), so to get the `<button>` just make your handler go up to the button even if you're already on it, like this:

```
buttons: {
  'button text': function(e){
     $(e.target).closest("button") //this is the button, do something with it :)
  }
}
```

[Here's a quick demo of this working](http://jsfiddle.net/8n7rq/)